Filebeat how to not generate dashboards automatically
I wanted to ask is there a configuration where I can disable Filebeat from automatically generating dashboards in Kibana? Most of the dashboards Filebeat generates are useless to me and it is a hassle to remove.
Filebeat dashboards
In the filebeat.yml file, loading in sample dashboards should be disabled by default. Should I uncomment the line setup.dashboards.enabled: false to ensure this setting is applied? Or is it possible to not setup filebeat with the command filebeat setup, thus not creating the dashboards. However, will filebeat start properly if I skip the setup?
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

You can skip loading dashboards by running the command:
filebeat setup -e --pipelines --index-management
This command only setups the pipelines and index management but not dashboards. Check this link for more info
